# How to create a window without minimize, maximized, and close button in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to know if tkinter can remove minimize, maximized and closed button on the upper right portion of the screen. Or is there any other python library can do this? If so, what is the code?

Comment: You can do this on `Toplevel` windows, but I don't think it can be done on root windows (instances of `Tk()`)

Comment: @JRiggles where is the difference ?

Comment: @Thingamabobs If I have `root = tk.Tk()` and set `root.transient()` it still shows the 'minimize' and 'maximize' buttons, but if I have `window = tk.Toplevel(root)` and `window.transient(root)`, only the 'close' button is shown like OP wants.

Comment: A transient window does more and less as OP question. I don't think it is a suitable answer to this question. Tkinter does not provide such functionality out of the box. But you can make it work with OS specific calls. Or you do `overrideredirect` and draw your own decoration.

Comment: @Thingamabobs is right. `overridedirect` works, but it's a bit trickier to deal with

Comment: Another idea if you have windows, you can use `root.attributes('-toolwindow', True)` to remove the minimize/maximize from the window and the you could just disable the x button with a callback.

Answer (score 0):

I explained this in a comment above, but I wanted to put it here for better readability. AFAIK, you can hide the minimize and maximize buttons on windows that are instances of `Toplevel`, but you can't do this on root windows that are instances of `Tk` - at least not using the method shown.

```
# basic example
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.transient()  # does nothing - min/max buttons are still shown
win = tk.Toplevel(root)
win.transient(root)  # works as intended - only close button is shown
root.mainloop()
```

```
# classy OOP example
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.transient()  # does nothing - min/max buttons are still shown
        self.win = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.win.transient(self)  # works as intended - only close button is shown
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The windows are not independent with `wm_transient`, you should mention that. They get `focused` together an should `map` and `unmap` together. `wm_transient` provides something like a `toolwindow`

Comment: At least under Windows, the transient and the root gets focused together, iconify and deiconify together, the transient is always on top of the root and so on. The windows are not independent from each other anymore.

Comment: @Thingamabobs I just tested this basic setup in Python with the root window and the transient Toplevel window by binding  `'<FocusIn>'` and  `'<FocusOut>'` events to the transient window. That works as expected. Minimizing/closing the root window *will* minimize/close the transient window, but like you said this is the typical behavior. And for the sake of completeness: maximizing the root window has no affect on the transient window.